# How to speed up neural network in google-colab with hdf5 files?

Tags: tensorflow, keras, hdf5, google-colaboratory

I am training a keras neural network in colab, that I want to speed it up. Here is my [code](https://colab.research.google.com/drive/1Wjzf9yZSW92Rr1vqcNgspVqm969b7NF4).  Training takes ~145sec/epoch on colab, while the same neural net trains for 5sec/epoch on a server with a k20 GPU. From what I [read](https://medium.com/@oribarel/getting-the-most-out-of-your-google-colab-2b0585f82403), the most probable cause for the slow training is that I have my training files in gdrive and accessing them from colab takes a lot of time. Supposedly, the solution is to do "memory mapping" of my data with the file format hdf5. The slow speed of training in colab seems to be a common problem, but I can't find any code solutions utilizing hdf5.

**I never used hdf5 before so can you give me some code examples about how to do the "mapping" in my code?** Any other suggestions for speeding up training are appreciated. I have also tried to:

- use larger `batch_size=` 256 or 512, but the speed didn't change
- skip the image augmentation in `ImageDataGenerator()`, but this saved only 25% of time
- use `tf.distribute.cluster_resolver` to distribute over multiple GPUs/TPUs, but I receive the error message "fit_generator is not supported for models compiled with tf.distribute.Strategy."

Thanks in advance, an answer should be useful to many more in the community!